# after installed ubuntu 17,10 ,unable to use gparted

Tags: partitioning, gparted

i installed Ubuntu as only operating system, i used the default partitioning scheme using the complete hard drive and now i want to add another partition for data? i used gparted, after input data, but there is no option to resize.

Comment: It very dangerous to repartition the boot drive. Backup your data, boot from Ubuntu LiveCD/USB and run gparted from here as [Gagan Rajput recommends](https://askubuntu.com/a/1006993/66509).

Answer (score 1):

For performing operation on hard drives and partitions they must be unmounted. Therefore you have to use **Live USB/CD** for performing that operation. [Link](https://askubuntu.com/a/237453/701605) provided by @karel will do the work for you.